# How to make react hook persists with ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-ref

I want to toggle an input element by using custom hook.

Here's my custom hook:

```js
import { RefObject, useEffect } from "react";

export const useEscape = (
  ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>,
  triggerFn: () => void
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        triggerFn();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
  });
};
```

and the example that would use the hook

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useEscape } from "./useEscape";

export default function App() {
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = React.useState(false);
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  useEscape(inputRef, () => {
    if (showInput) setShowInput(false);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {showInput && (
        <input ref={inputRef} placeholder="click outside to toggle" />
      )}

      {!showInput && (
        <span
          style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("toggle to trigger");
            setShowInput(true);
          }}
        >
          click to toggle input
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/useescape-hook-6lxh7?file=/src/App.tsx:0-716) to codesandbox demo.

Here's the issue. After I clicked on the `span` element to toggle into input state. After click outside of the input element, it would never able to toggle back to input state again.

I guess I know why's that happening. The react ref is still pointing to the `input` element that was created at the first place. Howeve, when react toggle to showing `span` state, it unmount the `input` element, and my custom hook never sync with React for the new `input` element. How can I customize my `useEscape` hook so the react ref would sync up? (By the way, I want to not use styling as a workaround which visually 'hides' the input element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { RefObject, useEffect } from "react";

export const useEscape = (
  ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>,
  triggerFn: () => void
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        triggerFn();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
  }, [ref, triggerFn]);
};
```

Your entire logic is absolutely correct. There is a slight error, instead of
window.removeEventListener, change it to document.removeEventListener.

You are removing event listener on global window object which leads to bug.